# script to use source file1 to lookup file2 for matching entries and print them into destination file3

Tags: find, match, lookup

I am looking to create a script that would allow me to use my source file containing "source ports" to look up into a log file, find matching "source port" then print the whole line out to a file.

there are approx 5000 source ports in a single column in my source file

Thank you for your help!
Kind Regards
B

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify too much details, but I assume it's about bash.

If so, for these example `ports` file:

```
80
443
8080
```

And `logs` file:

```
2016-01-01 www.google.pl:80 200 OK
2016-01-02 www.google.pl:22 200 OK
2016-01-03 www.google.pl:443 200 OK
2016-01-04 www.google.pl:80 200 OK
2016-01-05 www.google.pl:123 200 OK
```

This will work:

```
while read line           
do           
  ports[$line]=1           
done <ports

while read line
do
  [[ $line =~ :([[:digit:]]+) ]] && [[ ${ports[${BASH_REMATCH[1]}]} == 1 ]] && echo $line
done <logs >logs.filtered
```

It basically hashes ports in bash associative array and scans through the log file outputting on match.

Adjust the regexp and file format to your needs.

You could maybe achieve the same with the help of awk, join or other utils - but for that simple case this is enough.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your help, however I am getting the following when running the script

")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
./script.sh: line 9: 08: value too great for base (error token is "08")

Comment: Are you using bash (not ksh, sh, ...)? Can you provide exact inputs you are using?